# Python - Using same cookie with different request

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies

I need to make three requests with same cookie. If I make first request using this command:

```
s = requests.Session()
r1 = s.post("https://example.com/first.php", headers=headers1)
print(r1.cookies)
r2 = s.post("https://example.com/second.php", headers=headers1)
print(r2.cookies)
```

I get this output:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie PHPSESSID=3ht1qgfl4ot4lnrfemspkkk2ts for example.com/>]>
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

It seems there is not used same cookie in second request. I have tried also another approach:

```
r1 = requests.post("https://example.com/first.php", headers=headers1)
print(r1.cookies)
r2 = requests.post("https://example.com/second.php", headers=headers1, cookies=r1.cookies)
print(r2.cookies)
```

I get this output - same problem:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie PHPSESSID=mje0prfv97un49tkq381turq2d for example.com/>]>
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

Could someone help me, how to use same cookie in second request?

Answer (score 0):

It was written in requests docs about the cookies won't be sent in the second request

[https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#:~:text=This%20example%20will%20only%20send%20the%20cookies%20with%20the%20first%20request,%20but%20not%20the%20second](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#:%7E:text=This%20example%20will%20only%20send%20the%20cookies%20with%20the%20first%20request,%20but%20not%20the%20second)

I think you can try to store the cookies and load it

```python
import requests

s = requests.Session()
r1 = s.post("https://example.com/first.php", headers=headers1)
print(r1.cookies)
cookies = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(r1.cookies)
s.cookies.update(cookies)
r2 = s.post("https://example.com/second.php", headers=headers1)
print(r2.cookies)
r3 = s.post("https://example.com/third.php", headers=headers1)
print(r3.cookies)
```

you can see more information here https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#api-cookies